# What curves will satisfy this very intersting property?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

> Let $c_1,c_2\subset\mathbb R^2$ be differentiable curves. Given that for any rigid transformation  $E$ (i.e. combination of reflections, translations, rotations), if $c_1,E(c_2)$ intersect perpendicularly at one point then they will also intersect perpendicularly at any other intersection points. What are the possible $c_1,c_2$?

I can think of two possible situation (in a very very rough sense):

1. $c_1,E(c_2)$ can intersect perpendicularly at most once. I imagine this is the case when $c_1,c_2$ are "sufficiently straight", their turn angle is small.
2. $c_1,c_2$ are arc of circles, possibly circles of different radii.

Unfortunately, I can neither describe case 1 clearly, nor prove that there is no more other case. I wish see what ideas do you guys have. Thanks.

Comment: You should also allow straight lines (and segments) and circular arcs.

Comment: @ studiosus: Straight lines fall in case 1, while circles fall in case 2.

Comment: I meant that $c_1$ is a line and $c_2$ is a circle. Of course you can combine all these cases by saying that both curves have constant curvature.

Comment: It seems to me you can take any two curves $c_1$ and $c_2$ that make the same angle $\alpha$ at every one of their points of intersection. I can certainly draw fairly "random" curves with that property.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: The intersection property should hold not only for the curves themselves but also for all their images under rigid motions.

Comment: An example of (1) is when one curve is the straight line and the other is the graph of a smooth monotonic function.

Comment: @studiosus: Ah, so what I said works only for rotations fixing the intersection points. Silly me. Sorry.

Comment: @ studiosus, I get your point.